# Something Sort or Filter..iguess

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, reportviewer

can you help me because i want to display on the report viewer the dates that has no data recorded or inserted........ for example.. MARCH 2,3,5,7 has record.. i want to display on the report viewer that has no record MARCH 4,6.....something like that.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82qgr.png)

Comment: Do you have any code samples?

Comment: first build your calendar for the month then join it with your data set

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to build up your calendar then just a matter of join the calendar to your table

```
declare @mm varchar(2) = '02'
declare @yy varchar(4) = '2017'


select cast(@yy + '-' + @mm + '-' + cast(x.dd as varchar(2)) as date)
 from  
(select number [dd] from master..spt_values 
where type = 'p' 
and number between 1 and 31
) x 
where  isdate(cast(@yy + '-' + @mm + '-' + cast(x.dd as varchar(2)) as varchar(max))) = 1
order by x.dd
```